# Is it possible to emulate nfc tag via adb tools?

Tags: android, adb, nfc, nxp-microcontroller, bypass

Is anybody know, if it's possible to "make" my phone think that it has read a specific nfc ntag215 with specific UID? I was testing it on NFC tools pro.

Command I used:

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED --es android.nfc.extra.Tag "randomUIDgoeshere" -t "text/plain" --es "android.nfc.extra.TEXT" "Hello"`

Comment: Not every user is able to understand the gap between the command you have posted and what you want to achieve. You should thus edit your question and describe what you have achieved so far with the command and what is still missing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.